# How to -split with round brackets as delimiter?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a string that consist of round brackets:

```
$a = "Personal information(April 18, 2012)"
```

I require the information and date to be separated. So, I tried splitting the string with round brackets as delimiter.

Codes:

```
($a -split "(") -split ")"
```

The console gave me this error despite me switching the double quotes to single quotes:

```
Error: parsing "(" - Not enough )'s
```

How to split round brackets?

Comment: `$a.Split('(')[0]`. Since it splits the string into an array, you have to use the proper index number to get the first part that was split.

Comment: I am curious why does .Split() work and -split doesn't?

Comment: `(` is a metacharacter in regex, you'd need to escape it: `$a -split '\('`

Comment: Mathias beat me to it. Just needs to be escaped as `-Split` uses *Regex* matching where as the `Split()` method, reads it literal.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it now.